# How to show multiple highcharts on selection of few parameters and dynamically load JSON data using PHP page?

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

I have two parameters to load dynamic json data from mysql and visualise multiple line charts on page submit.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'get_pubmedid.php',
   type: 'get',
   data: {org: org, ptype: ptype, path: path,mirna: mirna},
   dataType: 'json',
   success:function(response) {
      var len = response.length;                   
      for( var i = 0; i<len; i++) {
         pubmed = response[i]['name'];
         cell=response[i]['cell'];
         alert(cell+"  "+pubmed+" "+len);
         var cells=encodeURIComponent(cell);
         var cname="charts"+(i+1);id=i+1;var pid=i+1;
         var container = cname;
         var func_name = cname;
         func_name = function () {
             Highcharts.chart(container, {
showhighcharts(org,ptype,path,mirna,cell,cells,pid,pubmed,cname,id);
             }             
         }
         func_name()     
      }
    }       
});


function showhighcharts(org,ptype,path,mirna,cell,cells,pid,pubmed,cname,id) {

 $("#"+cname).html("Wait, Loading graph...");
    var options = {
    chart: {
    type: 'line',
        renderTo: cname
    },
     colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'],
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Temporal Viewer',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {categories:<?php //echo $_SESSION["cat"]; ?>,
        offset:2,
         title: {enabled: true,text: 'Time Point' }
    },
    tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true,
    headerFormat: '<b>Time Point:{point.key}</b>  <table style="width:200px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td>Dosage:</td><td style="color: {series.color}">{series.name} </td></tr>' + '<tr><td>Fold Change:</td><td style="color: {series.color}">{point.y} </td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    enabled: true,
    crosshairs: {
            color: 'light gray',
            dashStyle: 'longdash'
        }

    },
            plotOptions: {
    series: {
            dashStyle: 'longdash'
        },
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            enableMouseTracking: true
        }
    },
    series: [{}]


};

    $.ajax({
    url: "jdatas.php?org="+org+"&ptype="+ptype+"&path="+path+"&mirna="+mirna+"&pid="+id+"&cell="+cell+"&pub="+pubmed,
    data: 'show=impressions',
    type:'get',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
    var getSeries = data;
    options.series = getSeries;
    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);         
    }
});
```

I want multiple graphs to be loaded on submit.

But its not showing any graph.

Comment: Could you provide the content of `getSeries` variable? How does it look like?

Comment: [{"name":"10 uM","data":[["24 h",1.5,"Time Point: 24 h","Regulation: Up"]]},{"name":"25 uM","data":[["24 h",2.6,"Time Point: 24 h","Regulation: Up"]]},{"name":"50 uM","data":[["24 h",2,"Time Point: 24 h","Regulation: Up"]]}]

Comment: please help to sort it.

Comment: Your data is not valid Highcharts data. Check how it should look like here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data